# How to configure TeamCity to run last successful build on failure?

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, teamcity

We're currently using TeamCity Enterprise 9.0 for our continuous deployment process; so please imagine the following scenario, you deploy your latest code to the dev branch, but one of the nugget packages was removed from the source and the build fails, QA team comes in at night and finds the build is broken and the environment is down for testing.

So I was wondering if there is a way to configure TeamCity to automatically run the last successful build in case the current code version fails, like configure it to make it aware that the current branch is broken and thus go back to a previous stable state.

Thanks,

Comment: Is there a reason you are deploying a failed build? Why not change the deployment to not proceed with a failed build.

Comment: Totally - Why would you deploy a broken build!

Comment: You need a target to *rollback* to a known good version

Comment: it is actually weird, because the deployment step is the last step and it is set to "Execute: If all previous steps finished successfully" but still we ended it up with failed builds in our dev environments, so I was looking at a fail over action that will ensure this doesn't happen.

Comment: I can provide a solution for your specific need, but just out of interest do you have any powershell steps that aren't actually successful (if you look in the build log and not just the step status)? If you can export a build log and share it (somewhere like dropcanvas) I can have a look through to find out what the real issue is.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to have a separate build configuration for Deployment task. In this case you will be able to configure artifact dependency with option get artifacts from "Latest successful build". 
Also see how to [set up deployment with TeamCity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/How+To...#HowTo...-SetupDeploymentforMyApplicationinTeamCity).